# Grant Permissions for User to View Tables after Connecting

Tags: oracle

I've granted select, update, insert and create session for a particular user for two tables.  When I log in with that user using SQL Developer, they can't see the tables.  Is there another permission for that?

Comment: What do you mean "can't see the tables"?  Are you executing a query?  Or are you referring to something in the user interface of SQL Developer?  If so, what part of the UI are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information (see my comment), my wager is that you are starting up SQL Developer, connecting to the database, and then opening the "Tables" section of the tree control and looking for the tables there.  If that is the case, you're looking in the wrong place.  In SQL Developer, you'd need to expand "Other Users", navigate to the user that owns the tables, and then open the "Tables" section of the tree control under that user in order to see the two tables.

If you are trying to run queries against the table, by default, you would need to provide fully qualified table names

```
SELECT *
  FROM owner_of_the_table.table_name
```

If you want to eliminate the need to use fully qualified table names, you can create synonyms for the tables (public or private).  Creating synonyms would be the conventional approach.  Alternately you can, at a session level, do

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = <<owner of the table>>
```

That would cause any unqualified references to be resolved using the specified schema rather than the current user's schema.

Comment: you're correct that I'm using SQL Developer and I'm logged in as system user but I don't see the two tables under the others users --> other user name --> tables, its empty

Comment: @c12 - So you are logging in as `SYSTEM`.  Did you grant `SYSTEM` access to the two tables?  What user owns the two tables?

Comment: I logged in as the system user and created the tables without an owner name.  I guess I should drop them and recreate using SYSTEM.table_name

Comment: @c12 - A table always has an owner.  The owner will be whatever user you are logged in as when you create the table.  Realistically, you should not be logging in to either the `SYS` or the `SYSTEM` schema to create new objects.  Objects should always be created in a new schema that you create not in one of the schemas that ships with Oracle.